# Maximization on trace of quadratic and linear terms under orthonormal constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I have the following optimization problem

$$ \max_{R: RR^{T}=I} \mbox{Tr} \left( M \left( R A R^{T} - K R^{T} \right) \right) $$

where:

- $A$ is a rank-one square matrix (assume the first row that are all positive, have been repeated for the next rows)
- $K$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix
- $M$ is a square, symmetric matrix with singular values $1$ or $0$, and $M^{2} = M$

How would one solve this optimization problem?

Comment: Something is wrong here. Is $R$ necessarily a square matrix? If not, then $RAR^T - KR^T$ is a subtraction of two matrices with different shapes. Should that be $RAR^T - RKR^T$?

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes R is an orthonormal matrix (and square). All the matrices are with dimension $d \times d$ with d an arbitrary integer.

Comment: Understood. As a point of terminology, if $R$ is a square matrix with orthonormal rows (or equivalently orthonormal columns), then it is called an **orthogonal** matrix.

Comment: This problem looks like it won't have an analytic/closed form solution

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone faces a similar problem, I learned that this is an optimization over Stiefel manifold which essentially is solved via iterative algorithms.

However, you can have a through review on these types of optimizations in this paper:

- A. Edelman, T. A. Arias, S. T. Smith, [The geometry of algorithms with orthogonality constraints](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479895290954), SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications, volume 20, number 2, pages 303–353, 1998.

Comment: Stiefel manifolds?  That is usually for tall matrices and you claimed $R$ is square.